# How do I add a new div containing message when a particular div is hovered on?

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I want to display a message when a certain text is hovered over. I can already have the required `div` in the markup and set the `opacity` to *"0"* and shift it to *"1"* when the text is hovered over. But how do I go about adding the entire message to the `div` via JavaScript?

```
.orange {
     display: block;
}

<div class="orange">ORANGE</div>

var check = document.getElementById('#orange');
if (check.matches(':hover')) {
    var checked = document.createElement('div');
    checked.innerHTML = "HELLO";
    checked.style.display = "block";
}
```

Here's the pen : https://codepen.io/callmesingham/pen/ymNeKg

Answer (score 1):

First `document.getElementById('#orange');` is wrong way to get element using id and `document.getElementById`. Secondly use `mouseover` & `mouseout` event and create the dom element with an id, so that once the mouse is out then the dynamically created element will also be removed.

```js
var check = document.getElementById('orange');

check.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  var checked = document.createElement('div');
  checked.id = 'hoverElem';
  let txtNode = document.createTextNode('Hello')
  checked.appendChild(txtNode)
  document.body.appendChild(checked)
});
check.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('hoverElem').remove()
})
```

```css
#orange {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="orange">ORANGE</div>
```